# Is verlan a form of minced oath?

Tags: verlan

So it came to my knowledge what a minced oath is (a deliberate misspelling/mispronunciation), and I thought, ohh so "meuf" is a minced oath.

But then my wife told me that is actually a verlan.

But then... It just made me think that every verlan is a minced oath. Aren't they?

Comment: ...A deliberate change of spelling or pronunciation **for swearing**.  This would benefit from more research on minced oaths.

Comment: "nomdidiou", and its variations should be a minced oath (for "nom de dieu"), while "meuf" is just "verlan". It's not a "classy" way to say "femme", especially since its uses might be different.

Answer (score 1):

Minced oath is a way to avoid swearing so it affects only a subset of the vocabulary while verlan is a form of rule based argot that can be used for essentially any word.

The original goal of verlan was to allow young people to communicate between themselves without being understood by the others, a kind of cryptic secret language. It used to be very popular in suburbs and was used extensively. Nowadays, only a limited number of words have survived and some of them are slowly becoming mainstream.

Comment: Actually verlan is very old and has known a revival in the past 30 years. Some words actually are old, verlan forms, like "barjot" (verlan of "jobard"). There are also "double verlan" forms like "rebeu", verlan of "beur", itself an old verlan form of "arabe".

Comment: @wazoox Yes, there are very old examples of verlan indeed, although the name itself came later. *Barjot* is certainly an example of verlan that went mainstream.

Comment: Verlan has been popular (for a limited and conventional set of words) starting mid 70s, e.g. the famous [Laisse béton](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gbD_x34hKWs) was on every lips in 1978 and remember the so [bléca Mr Mitterrand](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dBqhuL-rmVI) explaining in 1985 himself was familiar with verlan when he was young, that would be in the 30s (at 2:00). I think the goal was to be a social marker and social integration factor, like blue-jeans, Ray Bans or today the revival of archaic tatoos. Not necessarily a secret language or a practical purpose (in the 70s).

Comment: @mins La plupart (tous?) les mots d'argot commencent leur existence par une phase où ils ne sont compréhensibles que des initiés.